# How many lines can Qt draw on-screen?

Tags: qt

I am currently working on a Qt application to draw maps. I am trying to draw 400,000+ lines and it crashes after using ~2GB but I still have memory left on my machine. I am wondering if I am hitting some limit inside of Qt that is causing the problem. Anyone know if there is a limit to the number of things you can draw or if you can change this limit?

If it is helpful, I am coding in C++ with a class that has a member function to draw the lines. The code is roughly as follows

```
QPointF fromPoint;
QPointF toPoint;
fromPoint = foo( x );
toPoint = foo( y );
m_Painter.drawLine(fromPoint, toPoint );

//m_Painter is a QPainter
```

**Edit**: Turns out the problem was somewhere else in the code. It had to do with the custom caching that was being done. Though I am still interested if there is a limit to how many lines Qt can draw. Does anyone know?

Comment: 2GB looks like the 32 bits limitation for a process. Are you compiling for windows in 32 bits ?

Comment: Nope I am on a 64 bit machine

Comment: you're on a 64 bit machine, or you're compiling a 64 bit process? It's quite different...

Comment: Very good point. I am not sure but it looks like I am compiling for win32

Comment: I wonder what map it can be with 400000 lines on the screen? Maybe you have to draw only **visible** lines and not all of the map? So in this way you save your memory and speed up the app.

Comment: I am drawing all of the major highways in Europe with the data I have been given

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QPainter executes its underlying graphics through [QPaintEngine](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qpaintengine-members.html), which has several implementations (like [`qpaintengine_mac.cpp`](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/57756e72adf2081137b97f0e689dd16c770d10b1:src/gui/painting/qpaintengine_mac.cpp), [`qpaintengine_x11.cpp`](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/57756e72adf2081137b97f0e689dd16c770d10b1:src/gui/painting/qpaintengine_x11.cpp), or [`qpaintengine_preview.cpp`](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/57756e72adf2081137b97f0e689dd16c770d10b1:src/gui/painting/qpaintengine_preview.cpp)).

Some devices are raster...and are likely drawing each line into an image buffer and throwing away the endpoints after that drawing is done.  There should be no limit to the number of lines you can draw in that case.

If the target device is OpenGL, or to a printer that is doing some kind of PostScript-like output, then the limitations of that particular paint engine may well be a factor.  You'd have to look at the specific one.

For example: if you trace down the X11 implementation of drawLine you'll see it passes through to `drawPolygon()` down through `strokePolygon_dev()`...and bottoms out at a call to [XDrawLines](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/graphics/drawing/XDrawLines.html):

```
XDrawLines(dpy, hd, gc, pts, numberPoints, CoordModeOrigin);
```

So there you have another abstraction layer...and so the question becomes whether the XWindows display parameter is guaranteed to be raster.  (My guess would be that it is.)

Anyway, so the answer is *"unlimited if raster.  may depend otherwise--but the limitations (if any) are probably coming from the underlying device for the paint engine, not Qt."*